# How can i fix some broken packages PyQt packages?

Tags: 11.04, installation, apt, package-management, pyqt

I'm trying to install PyQt but i've met some difficulties (i.e packages that won't be updated and stuff like that). I'm not very proficient with Ubuntu, so some help is needed. Here's the output i get from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-qt4 : Depends: libqt4-declarative (>= 4:4.7.0~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-designer (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-help (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-script (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-scripttools (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-svg (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-test (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't install the but python-qt4 because the libqt4* packages are not found in the repositories.
My guess is that you are missing one of the canonical repositories so will you please launch *Software Sources* and under *Ubuntu Software* tab make sure it is set similar to:

[image]

After changing setting make sure you run `sudo apt-get update`. You are then ready to retry the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you refreshed your repositories? If not, try: `sudo apt-get update` and then try to install again.

You can also try the following command if there is some broken package issue on your system: `sudo apt-get check`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure using

sudo apt-get update

and then

sudo apt-get install -f

will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

terminal: `gksudo nautilus`

navigate to /var/lib/dpkg/info
remove the broken package(s) libqt4

navigate to /var/lib/dpkg/status
and do the same.
(Mind: on the right is a search option to find the package(s))

Close nautilus.

important:  `sudo apt-get update`

```
         sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you think that the dpkg database is broken, but broken or not, editing it by hand sounds like a reallly good way to break a system beyond recovery. Please don't recommend it to users unless you have *very* compelling evidence that that's needed.